# Can a REST Service Controller read a text file which is located at the path given in request param?

Tags: java, restful-architecture

My requirement is to create a `java` `restful web service` which reads a text file and pull out some information from that text file. I am new to `restful web services` so I don't know exactly how to code this. I am thinking there would be a `REST Service Controller` which has a `post` `HTTP method` that takes a file path as a `request parameter`.

**Now I wonder how that rest controller has an access to that file or can rest controller read it and extract information from that file?**

Comment: Where is the file? On the webservice's host? On a remote server? On the client or attached to the post body?
The answer will be very different depending on where the file is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location to the file would not be enough, you will need to send the protocol to connect to the location of the file, the timeout for the connection, and if the protocol needs some authentication you need to verify it and send the required parameters.

Implementing the rest controller is not issue, after exposing an api you can use InputStream to read the content of the file, check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much.